# how to test toast messages using appium 1.6.3

Tags: appium

I want to verify if a toast message is displayed in android app insutumentation , I am using appium 1.6.3 to do this . I have checked in many links but couldn't find solution , can somebody suggest a solution.

Comment: did you try by mentioning the automationName aswith uiautomator2 in Capabilities?

Comment: I have set the property setCapability("automationName","uiautomator2") . still it is not working . Can you please provide an example ?

Comment: Are we talking about SnackBar toast message?

Answer (score 1):

From Appium version 1.6.3 supports toast messages, for that you need to use `automationName:'uiautomator2'.`

```
  toast = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//android.widget.Toast[1]")
  if toast.text == "Hello"
```

But i don't recommend this because uiautomator2 is not stable yet.

Comment: Nice! Thanks it helped me.